# $l^1$ norm estimate for inverse of Vandermonde matrix

Tags: numerical-linear-algebra

As title, I would like to know the known upper bound for the $l^1$ norm for inverse of Vandermonde matrix. A quick search gives [this paper](http://www.springerlink.com/index/T05M860674778382.pdf) by Gautschi 40 years ago, but it deals with the infinity norm instead. Thanks!

**Motivation**: Part 2 of [this problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/281315/let-a-i-in-mathbbr-i-1-2-dots-n-and-fx-sum-i-0na-ixi-s)

Comment: The link to the paper by Gautschi at `springerlink.com` is broken. It should probably point to the following one: _Gautschi, Walter_, [**Norm estimates for inverses of Vandermonde matrices**](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01438260), Numer. Math. 23, 337–347 (1975). [Zbl 0304.65031](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0304.65031).